# Loops Function on Json Array Object

Tags: php, json, loops

I do not know if this is possible or not, I should ask rather than just be quiet, can json array result using loops? for example
i have loops script like this

```
$count = count($json);
if($count > 10){
$count = 10;
}
for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
...
}
```

and then, i have a json array that only has 1 path, json is like this

```
array (
  'type' => 'template',
  'altText' => 'this is a carousel template',
  'template' => 
  array (
    'type' => 'carousel',
    'columns' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'thumbnailImageUrl' => 'https://example.com/images/item1.jpg',
        'imageBackgroundColor' => '#FFFFFF',
        'title' => 'this is menu',
        'text' => 'description',
        'actions' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'type' => 'postback',
            'label' => 'Buy',
            'data' => 'action=buy&itemid=111',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

is there a way for my loops function to work on json array above? so for path ['template']['columns'] can generate 10 paths according to the number of loops I have, so the result is like this if the loops function just 2

```
array (
  'type' => 'template',
  'altText' => 'this is a carousel template',
  'template' => 
  array (
    'type' => 'carousel',
    'columns' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'thumbnailImageUrl' => 'https://example.com/images/item1.jpg',
        'imageBackgroundColor' => '#FFFFFF',
        'title' => 'this is menu',
        'text' => 'description',
        'actions' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'type' => 'postback',
            'label' => 'Buy',
            'data' => 'action=buy&itemid=111',
          ),
        ),
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'thumbnailImageUrl' => 'https://example.com/images/item1.jpg',
        'imageBackgroundColor' => '#FFFFFF',
        'title' => 'this is menu',
        'text' => 'description',
        'actions' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'type' => 'postback',
            'label' => 'Buy',
            'data' => 'action=buy&itemid=111',
          ),
        ),
      ),          
    ),
  ),
)
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you want. But this is my understanding about your question

```
$jsson = array (
                'type' => 'template',
                'altText' => 'this is a carousel template',
                'template' => 
                array (
                  'type' => 'carousel',
                  'columns' => 
                  array (
                    0 => 
                    array (
                      'thumbnailImageUrl' => 'https://example.com/images/item1.jpg',
                      'imageBackgroundColor' => '#FFFFFF',
                      'title' => 'this is menu',
                      'text' => 'description',
                      'actions' => 
                      array (
                        0 => 
                        array (
                          'type' => 'postback',
                          'label' => 'Buy',
                          'data' => 'action=buy&itemid=111',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
    for($i=1; $i < 2; $i++){
        $jsson['template']['columns'][$i] = $jsson['template']['columns'];
    }
```